# Do I have to use an animation to change an Android activity's view?

Tags: java, android

Everywhere I look online, it seems that I must use an animation to change views dynamically (like slide in, out). Do I have to do this, or can I simple just setContentView() on each new activity?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's nothing to say you have to use an animation.  Just create your `intent` object, start your activity with `startActivity` or `startActivityForResult`, and then call `setContentView` when it loads.  No animation necessary.

HTH.